# Parcel Serve returns 404 due to adding hash to index.html

Tags: parcel

Started using parcel for the first time. I've setup parcel in my project and ran the `parcel serve src/index.html`.

The build succeeds, but when I go to the url, I get a 404 error:
[image: http://localhost:1234/]

When I inspect the `dist` folder I find my files there, but the index file itself has a hash, so calling http://localhost:1234/index.html returns a 404

[image]

But calling http://localhost:1234/index.html.4183.0 works
[image]

How do I tell parcel to correctly build the index.html without the extra hash? i have tried no-content-hash to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with 404 when running a parcel dev server and noticed that in my case it was happening only after I did reboot my machine.

After some investigation I found that the 404 issue which I was observing was related to `.parcel-cache` folder. When I was clearing it out problem did not happen. After consulting with docs - https://parceljs.org/features/cli/ - I found `--no-cache` option which helped to resolve the issue entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue of getting 404 page not found error when running a parcel dev server. It got fixed when I updated my npm package to the latest version. If npm update is causing any errors, then try uninstalling node and npm from global (which might be older version) and install new versions.

I followed the steps mentioned in following blog and it worked for me.  https://radixweb.com/blog/installing-npm-and-nodejs-on-windows-and-mac

Comment: Welcome to the StackOverflow! The question is not about "how to install nodejs". So, try to focus on the question. Also, please clarify if you don't know the final solution.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this issue. My environment is parcel@2.8.3, node@12.7.0 and npm@6.10.0. When I switched nvm to node@18.15.0, and npm@9.5.0, it worked normally.

Comment: Downgrading isn't a valid answer/solution.